# Java PDF format error

Tags: java

I have to create an new class to create an new pdf file in java.
This is my code.

```
public class Createpdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\dev\\training\\practice\\java\\30-09-2015\\Invoice.pdf"));
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(new FileOutputStream("concatenatedforms.pdf"));
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            file.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But while opening the file it displays but shows error "There is a problem with file format" I am a beginner may I know the exact problem

Comment: I already have the PDF in my system and just need to create another PDF using java by copying the file.

Comment: What is `PdfReader`? What is `PdfCopyFields`? From which library are those? Can you open and view the referenced file with a PDF reader?

Comment: If you just need to copy the file, you can do that using just `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` - you don't need a `PdfReader` at all.

Comment: I m using itext library

Comment: I have to copy and create new PDF file

Comment: Do you need to change anything in the PDF file while copying? Or is it only a binary, one-to-one copy? If thats the case, use the suggestion from @JonSkeet

Comment: @Andreas I could open the reference file in reader

Comment: I do not want to change but my task is to create an new PDF using java same like the invoice file

Comment: That's fine I have been asked to create the same pdf as I am having one given to me as task thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the error use this code below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(new    File("C:\\temp\\528.pdf"));
        FileOutputStream copy = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\concatenatedforms.pdf");
        int b;
        while ((b = file.read()) != -1) {
            copy.write(b);
        }
        file.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.Amir I said you should put the right path in the code above like my answer

Comment: i tried that before itself but could not open the new pdf it shows me error thank you @ Adbelhak

Comment: @M.Amir for me create the file pdf in the specific path ,,NO error

Comment: The program runs fine and the pdf with the name is created in the destination folder when itry to open it shows error "File format not supported"

Comment: Thanks for your help but it the answer is related to java I\O not an pdf jar